# Using custom layouts in Java and XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm making a chat app in Android Studio and I've written a couple of XML layout files for displaying the messages:

bubble_send.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bubble_send_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_send_user"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Me" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bubble_send_text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_send_bg"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="Dummy text send" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and bubble_receive.xml which is basically the same except aligned differently.

I want to change the text values of both TextViews in the RelativeLayout with Java and then append the whole RelativeLayout as a message frame to a vertically aligned LinearLayout in the chat activity.

I have already tried researching the matter, but I can only find solutions using ListView and RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout, which are not suitable for my task.

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Take nested scroll view add  parent linear layout to that , then whenever you get message try creating child linear layout with two textview set message to textview then add to child linear layout.
Scroll view -
     Parent linear layout with vertical orientation-
               (Child1
                  Text11
                   Text12)
             ( Child2
                   Text21
                    Text22)
    .............?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to create custom view that will inherit `RelativeLayout`. If you are coding in Java you should write something like this.

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

    private TextView sendUserBubble;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ini();
    }

    private void initView() {
        // Pass your xml layout here that you already created
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.your_custom_layout, this);
        sendUserBubble = findViewById(R.id.bubble_send_user);
    }
    public void setSendTextUser(String text) {
        sendUserBubble.setText(text)
    }
```

After that, you use it inside your chat activity xml file, something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_activity_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <MyView
        android:id="@+id/my_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

And reference this inside your activity code:

```
MyView view = findViewById(R.id.my_view)
view.setSendTextUser("My awesome text")
```